# Comparing binary values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, binary, bitcount

Say you have two binary values

```
001011 
001111
```

How can you get the number of different bits in MySQL? I tried

```sql
SELECT BIT_COUNT(BINARY  001011 ^ BINARY 001111)
```

This returns 6, while I need a solution that returns 1 in this example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT BIT_COUNT( CONV( '001011', 2, 10 ) ^ CONV( '001111', 2, 10 ) )
```

Comment: How about for large binary strings? It seems to cap out at 2^16 or thereabout.

Comment: I'm using MySql 5.1 and it doesn't seem to have a cap `SELECT CONV( '11111111111111111111111111111111', 2, 10 )` returns `4294967295` as expected.

Comment: I'm trying this example:
SELECT BIT_COUNT( CONV( 1111111110011111000001000000111000000110100011001111011101010100, 2, 10 ) ^ CONV( 1111111110011111000001000001111000000110100011010000000110010000, 2, 10 ) )

(there are a couple of bits different in the middle somewhere, but it returns 0)
thanks again.

Comment: @Sheqel After doing some tests I figured out there is a 63bit limit, I suppose it's related to the sign bit. BTW put the first argument between quotes or it will be interpreted as a base10 number.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT BIT_COUNT(b'001011' ^ b'001111');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's converting the numbers 1011 and 1111 (base 10) to binary and doing the comparison.  If you did:

```
SELECT BIT_COUNT(11 ^ 15)
```

It'd work.

Comment: actually, the leading 0's make MySQL see those as octal numbers.

Comment: How about for large binary strings? It seems to cap out at 2^16 or thereabout.

Comment: Didnt know that mysql converted 0nnn to octal.  Thanks for enlightening me.